# Unable to determine the workspace using TF.exe

Tags: scripting, tfs, tfsbuild, workspace

I have this script (bat file)

```
tf workspaces /s:http://project02:8080

tf workspace /s:http://project02:8080 Team.descomp;MyDomain\Myuser


tf workfold /workspace:Team.descomp


tf get $/Team/Main/Projects /recursive /force /noprompt
```

I get this error: Unable to determine the workspace., when I try execute tf get.

Console output is similar like:

> Server: project02
>
> Workspace: DESCOMP
>
> Owner    : MyUser
>
> Computer : DESCOMP
>
> Workspace: Team.descomp
>
> Owner    : MyUser
>
> Computer : DESCOMP
>
> ...
>
> Workspace: Team.descomp (MyUser)
>
> Server   :
>   http://project02:8080/
>
> $/Team: C:\Temp\Team2
>
> ...
>
> Unable to determine the workspace.

Note, for $/Team (team project) has map in two machines: MyUser and Descomp

> Workspace: Team Owner    : MyUser
>   Computer : MyUser
>
> Workspace: Team.descomp Owner    :
>   MyUser Computer : DESCOMP

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From Forums MSDN: Mr. Hofman

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsbuild/thread/82b13bfd-5fd7-45f7-a681-d84c9ea52765

Change the working folder for the tf get to a folder that is mapped by the workspace.

Execute the command from a folder where the workspace is mapped

(for example if you do it from console:

```
cd c:\sources\myteamproject

tf get ...
```

)

---

Key: Change the working folder for the tf get to a folder that is mapped by the workspace.

I use command **pushd C:\Temp\Team2** in my script file.

**Update**: Comments by Ryan Cromwell

You can create and map a workspace in your script with the following.  The second command works, because the first workspace is created in the 'blah' folder.  The '.' in the second command is saying map '$/' to the current directory (blah). You could change that to be a named folder or subfolder if you choose.

**Create a new workspace**
`C:\projects\blah>tf workspace /new blah /noprompt /collection:http://<host>:<port>/tfs/<collection> /login:<username>,<pwd>`

**Map a path in that workspace**
`C:\projects\blah>tf workfold /map $/ . /login:<username>,<pwd>`

Comment: You can also map a workspace at the command line with tf workspace.

Answer (score 7):

This extends @Kiquenet answer.  It wasn't easily done in the comments :(

You can create and map a workspace in your script with the following.  The second command works, because the first workspace is created in the 'blah' folder.  The '.' in the second command is saying map '$/' to the current directory (blah). You could change that to be a named folder or subfolder if you choose.

**Create a new workspace**
`C:\projects\blah>tf workspace /new blah /noprompt /collection:http://<host>:<port>/tfs/<collection> /login:<username>,<pwd>`

**Map a path in that workspace**
`C:\projects\blah>tf workfold /map $/ . /login:<username>,<pwd>`

Comment: If you're creating these for temporary folders, it's good practice to delete them (via `tf workspace /delete`) when you're done (as well as the temporary folder).

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem in team city executing a ps1 file with the following:

```
tf resolve FND.sql /auto:KeepYours

tf checkout FND.sql /noprompt

tf checkin FND.sql /noprompt
```

when I executed it in a PS window, it worked fine, but when executed by Team City, I got the following response for each tf call:

```
Unable to determine the workspace. ...
```

Trying to obtain more information about what was going on, I inserted the following statement before the 1st tf call:

```
tf workfold
```

when I ran Team City the next time, the tf workfold showed the mapping that was not previously recognized, and the existing tf commands started working.

It still worked when I took out the tf workflold command.

I don't understand it, but maybe this will work for other people with this problem.

I had previously tried several recommendations from this and other websites without success.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Somehow `tf workfold` is able to recognize workspaces that `tf workspace` can’t. Basically, you would map a folder with `tf workfold`. tf.exe may hang at this point. Just kill it and then run `tf workspace` and it should work now. You might have to try 2 or 3 times.

Comment: Example command `tf workfold /workspace:"wkspaceEg" /collection:http://tfs.example.com:8080/tfs/collectionEg /login:TFSUsername,TFSPassword /map $/teamProjEg D:\Legacy.00\TFS\Source\Workspaces\teamProjEg`. You cannot specify the workspace owner’s username in this command. It will only try with `TFSUsername` as owner.