# Unable to determine Workspace using TFS API in C# and TF.exe within TeamCity 9.1.3

Tags: c#, tfs, nant, teamcity-9.0

I'm working on a Nant build script and attempting to get latest of ProjectInfo.vb and ProjectInfo.cs from C:\workspaces\myproject\thisfolder. In doing so I've tried using both a custom task written in C# and also using the NAnt Exec task to launch TF.EXE. I get the same error with both.

> Unable to determine workspace

TF.exe returns error 100. The custom task throws an exception (unfortunately I don't have the exact type of exception written down) but the message returned is the same as when using TF.exe.

UPDATE: I have VS2013 Ultimate with Update 5 installed on the BuildServer running Windows 7 Professional SP1 and attempting to access TFServer 2010.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

The error happens when the tf command is unable to determine the workspace. So, you need to either change the working folder to workspace folder, or create a workspace mapping in the current folder.

Check Kiquenet's reply in this link for the details: [Unable to determine the workspace using TF.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863865/unable-to-determine-the-workspace-using-tf-exe)

Key steps are quoted for your quick reference:

1. Create a new workspace
   C:\projects\blah>tf workspace /new blah /noprompt /collection:http://:/tfs/ /login:,
2. Map a path in that workspace
   C:\projects\blah>tf workfold /map $/ . /login:,